# Why my sqlite insert method is not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sqliteopenhelper

## Save data with SQLite

Hi guys, I'm new to Android and i'm working in a Notes App, until now I have done with the main interphace and recieve the inputs from the Edittext, but when it comes to saving data to my SQLite DB, my code is failling, can you please tell me what I been doing wrong ?.

### FormActivity method

```
public void saveToDB(View view) {

    try {

        String subjet = asunto.getText().toString();
        String body = cuerpo.getText().toString();

        int day = myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int month = myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int year = myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        Note note = new Note(subject,body,day,month,year); // Create an instance of Note class
        DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this,"TaskList.db",null,1); // New Instance of DBHelper class
        db.InsertIntoTable(note); // pass the newly created Note instance to DBHelper insert method

        db.close(); // we close Database

        Toast.makeText(this,"Note saved !!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // Notify the user of the operation success

        Intent intent = new Intent(FormActivity.this,MainActivity.class); // Lets return to MainActivity again
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Unable to save note",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

### DBHelper insert method

```
public Long InsertIntoTable(Note note){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    /* We organize the values in the respective rows */

    values.put(col_subject,note.getSubject());
    values.put(col_note,note.getBody());
    values.put(col_day,note.getDay());
    values.put(col_month,note.getMonth());
    values.put(col_year, note.getYear());

    // Time to insert data to Database
    long rowID = db.insert(table_name,null,values);
    return rowID;
}
```

**I put a Toast, to prevent my app from crashing in case and to see if the operation succed, but it fails everytime.**

### RecyclerAdapter class

```
@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.itemview,null);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    Note note = noteList.get(i);

    viewHolder.asunto.setText(note.getAsunto());
    viewHolder.nota.setText(note.getCuerpo());
    viewHolder.fecha.setText(note.getDia() + "/" + note.getMes() + "/" + note.getAno());
    viewHolder.etiqueta.setText(note.getTag());
}
```

## This is in my stacktrace:

**E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout**

Comment: We can get why it is not inserting into DB when we look into stack trace. Can you show the stack trace?

Comment: Please add crash stack trace

Comment: you are ignorring the exception. Check it's stacktrace and type to see what is a problem